# Using compression library to estimate information complexity of an english sentence?

Tags: python, scala, compression, information-theory

I'm trying to write an algorithm that can work out the 'unexpectedness' or 'information complexity' of a sentence. More specifically I'm trying to sort a set of sentences so the least complex come first.

My thought was that I could use a compression library, like zlib?, 'pre train' it on a large corpus of text in the same language (call this the 'Corpus') and then append to that corpus of text the different sentences.

That is I could define the complexity measure for a sentence to be how many more bytes it requires to compress the whole corpus with that sentence appended, versus the whole corpus with a different sentence appended. (The fewer extra bytes, the more predictable or 'expected' that sentence is, and therefore the lower the complexity). Does that make sense?

The problem is with trying to find the right library that will let me do this, preferably from python.

I could do this by literally appending sentences to a large corpus and asking a compression library to compress the whole shebang, but if possible, I'd much rather halt the processing of the compression library at the end of the corpus, take a snapshot of the relevant compression 'state', and then, with all that 'state' available try to compress the final sentence. (I would then roll back to the snapshot of the state at the end of the corpus and try a different sentence).

Can anyone help me with a compression library that might be suitable for this need? (Something that lets me 'freeze' its state after 'pre training'.)

I'd prefer to use a library I can call from Python, or Scala. Even better if it is pure python (or pure scala)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this is going to do is tell you whether the words in the sentence, and maybe phrases in the sentence, are in the dictionary you supplied. I don't see how that's complexity. More like grade level. And there are better tools for that. Anyway, I'll answer your question.

Yes, you can preset the zlib compressor a dictionary. All it is is up to 32K bytes of text. You don't need to run zlib on the dictionary or "freeze a state" -- you simply start compressing the new data, but permit it to look back at the dictionary for matching strings. However 32K isn't very much. That's as far back as zlib's deflate format will look, and you can't load much of the English language in 32K bytes.

LZMA2 also allows for a preset dictionary, but it can be much larger, up to 4 GB. There is a Python binding for the LZMA2 library, but you may need to extend it to provide the dictionary preset function.

Comment: Thanks heaps for taking the time. 

You may be right that it may not be interesting, but I'm gonna have a bit more of a try. I do agree that with only 32K of 'dictionary' it may not be all that interesting, but thinking a well optimized dictionary, even if it has only a few 'patterns' in it could still tell you quite a bit about sentences that use the most common structures, versus others.  Even PySmaz a w teeny tiny 256 *entry* dictionary does not totally meaningless things https://github.com/CordySmith/PySmaz/blob/master/smaz/__init__.py#L295  show that it is